# Redirecttopage not working properly. url encoded and duplicated in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, http-redirect

Ok, this is my add page:
frontend:

```
@page
@model as_quebec.Pages.Admin.Links.AddModel
@{
}

<div class="bg-secondary bg-opacity-10 py-2 mb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="title">Ajouter un lien</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label id="titleTitle" for="title" class="form-label">Titre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" asp-for="AddLinkRequest.Title">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label id="titleWebLink" for="webLink" class="form-label">Lien du site</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="webLink" asp-for="AddLinkRequest.WebLink">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

backend:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class AddModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILinkRepository _linkRepository;

        [BindProperty]
        public AddLink AddLinkRequest { get; set; }

        public AddModel(ILinkRepository linkRepository)
        {
            _linkRepository = linkRepository;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Ajouter un lien";
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            var link = new Link
            {
                Title = AddLinkRequest.Title,
                WebLink = AddLinkRequest.WebLink
            };
            await _linkRepository.AddAsync(link);

            var notification = new Notification
            {
                Type = Enums.NotificationType.Success,
                Message = "Nouveau lien ajouté."
            };

            TempData[Constants.NotificationId] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(notification);

            return RedirectToPage("/Admin/Links/List");
        }
    }
```

When onPost is triggered, it should redirect to this page:
frontend:

```
@page "{page?}"
@model as_quebec.Pages.Admin.Links.ListModel
@{
    Pager pager = new Pager();

    int pageNo = 0;

    if (Model.Pager != null)
    {
        pager = Model.Pager;
        pageNo = pager.CurrentPage;
        pager.BaseUrl = "/admin/links/list";
    }
}
@using as_quebec.Models;

<div class="bg-secondary bg-opacity-10 py-2 mb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="title">Liens</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<partial name="_Notification">

    @if (Model.Links != null && Model.Links.Any())
    {
        <partial name="~/Pages/Shared/_Pager.cshtml" model="@pager" />
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="columnTitle" class="text-center">Titre</th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var textPost in Model.Links)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td id="title-@textPost.Id" align="center">@textPost.Title</td>
                            <td align="right"><a id="linkToModify-@textPost.Id" href="/Admin/Links/Edit/@textPost.Id">Modifier</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <partial name="~/Pages/Shared/_Pager.cshtml" model="@pager" />
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="container">
            <p id="notFoundLinksMsg">Aucun lien n'a été trouvé</p>
        </div>
    }
```

Backend:

```
public class ListModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILinkRepository _linkRepository;
        [BindProperty]
        public List<Link> Links { get; set; }

        public Pager Pager { get; set; }

        public ListModel(ILinkRepository linkRepository)
        {
            _linkRepository = linkRepository;
        }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Liste des liens";
            var notificationJson = (string)TempData[Constants.NotificationId];
            if (notificationJson != null)
            {
                ViewData[Constants.NotificationId] = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Notification>(notificationJson);
            }

            Links = (await _linkRepository.GetAllAsync())?
                .Reverse()
                .ToList();

            if (int.TryParse(Request.Query["page"], out int page))
            {
                InitializePage(page);
            }
            else
            {
                InitializePage(1);
            }
        }

        private void InitializePage(int page)
        {
            const int pageSize = Constants.NumberOfElementByPage;
            if (page < 1)
            {
                page = 1;
            }

            int recsCount = Links.Count();

            var pager = new Pager(recsCount, page, pageSize);

            int recSkip = (page - 1) * pageSize;

            Links = Links.Skip(recSkip).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList();

            Pager = pager;
        }
    }
```

But when I add a link, the return RedirectToPage("/Admin/Links/List"); is called but it is reirecting to this in local:  **https://localhost:7042/Admin/Links/List/%2FAdmin%2FLinks%2FList** instead of `https://localhost:7042/Admin/Links/List`. Do you know what I am doing wrong? It is like the url is dupplicated and encoded the second time...

This is my Program class:

```
using as_quebec.Data;
using as_quebec.Helpers;
using as_quebec.Repositories;
using as_quebec.Repositories.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Load environment variable
DotNetEnv.Env.Load();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ASQuebecDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ASQuebecDbConnectionString"))
);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthenticationDbConnectionString"))
);

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Default setting password
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(
    options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
    }  
);

builder.Services.AddScoped<ITextPostRepository, TextPostRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILinkRepository, LinkRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IImageRepository, ImageRepositoryCloudinary>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITagRepository, TagRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITagManagementRepository, TagManagementRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITextPostLikeRepository, TextPostLikeRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITextPostCommentRepository, TextPostCommentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailManager, EmailManager>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

public partial class Program { }
// </snippet_all>
```

Comment: You haven't provided a route parameter called `page`, eg `RedirectToPage("/Admin/Links/List", new { page = "something"})`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That's not the issue. The parameter is marked as optional.

Comment: Does this happen to all pages or just this one?

Comment: `page` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a route parameter in Razor Pages. Change it to `currentPage` or something similar.